# Formatting a message Laravel Collective

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.2

Hello I have this message in my controller:

```
public function postIndex(SaveProfileRequest $request) {
    $profile = Profile::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name')
        ]);

    if($profile->id) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', [
            'type'=> 'success',
            'message' => 'Успешно записан нов профил!'

        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', [
        'type'=> 'danger',
        'message' => 'Профилът не е записан!'
    ]);
}
```

I'm displaying it like this:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    {{ Session::get('message.message')}}
@endif
```

But it doesn't show in the type i have selected in the controller, how can I format it?

Thank you!

Comment: `$message->type` will give you the type and `$message->message` will give the Warning/Success message. 

Now in your view, u can call it as `{{ $message->type }}` and `{{ $message->message }}`

Comment: yeah, but how i put this in {{ Session::get('message.message')}}

Comment: If you want to use Session, you can call it like : `{{Session::get('message')['message']}}`

Comment: Yep, but it doesn't work. I'm sorry I am new in this and  guess I cant get the idea right...

Comment: If you just want to display the message in the view, just use {{ $message->message }}

Comment: Since you are not using session, follow the code I gave above.

Comment: I'm using session and when I write this 
 @if(Session::has('message'))
    <p>{{ Session::get('message')['message']}}</p>
@endif

the message is the same...

Comment: Not like this. You've to create a session variable from your controller to use it in your view. Did you try the solution I provided?

Comment: Display your message like: `{{ $message->message }}` instead of the one you provided.

Comment: @if(Session::has('message'))
    <div>{{ $message->message }}</div>
@endif 

like this?

Comment: Don't use Session::has('message').  Just use `@if(!empty ( $message ) ) {{ $message->message }} @endif`

Comment: It doesn't show at all...

Comment: In your view, try {{ var_dump($message) }} . Did you see anything?

Comment: Still doesn't show, I have to use Session, it works when I have it just it's not formatted

Comment: Where are you using the type in in view

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 'message' to 'status' so your code should look like this.

```
public function postIndex(SaveProfileRequest $request) {

    $profile = Profile::create(['name' => $request->input('name')]);

     if($profile->id) {
        return redirect()->back()->with(['message' => 'Успешно записан нов профил!', 'type' => 'success']);
     }

     return redirect()->back()->with(['message', => 'Профилът не е записан!', 'type' => 'danger']);
}
```

Then you can access your message from the page like this:

```
@if (session('status'))
     {{ session('message') . "<br>" }}
     {{ session('type') }}

@endif
```

Comment: The message is shown in my page, just it is not with type danger and etc. The thing you suggest work but it's not what I want..

Comment: Please check my second answer. That should help you.

Comment: Alright, I updated this answer and  verified this on brand new laravel setup. So it's working.

Comment: Not working for me... I didn't see the msg at all now.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you is to change the "with" with withInput.

```
public function postIndex(SaveProfileRequest $request) {
    $profile = Profile::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name')
       ]);

   if($profile->id) {
       return redirect()->back()->withInput(['message' => [
           'type'=> 'success',
            'message' => 'Успешно записан нов профил!'
        ]]);
    }

   return redirect()->back()->withInput(['message' => [
       'type'=> 'danger',
       'message' => 'Профилът не е записан!'
   ]]);
}
```

Then you can access them in your view.

```
{{ $message->$message }}
{{ $message->type }}
```

Comment: @if(Session::has('message'))
    <div>{{ $message->$message }}
        {{ $message->type }}</div>
@endif


in my view like this?